# Spring security and API versioning

Tags: spring-security, jersey

I'm building an authentication layer with Spring Security on top of a Jersey RESTful application. The Jersey application is a "versioned" API, which routes to the right version handler based on the `Content-Type`.

My question is: since different API versions will have different authentication mechanisms, what is the best way to handle this in Spring Security? Should I have a different `AuthenticationFilter` for each authentication mechanism? Should I build in knowledge at the Spring Security layer of which `AuthenticationFilter`'s should be applied for each version (`Content-Type`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could define different filter chains for the different API versions and use a `RequestMatcher` to match based on the `Content-Type` header of the request.

```
<bean id="apiV1Matcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('Content-Type','<pattern for api v1>')"/>
</bean>

<bean id="apiV2Matcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.ELRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg value="hasHeader('Content-Type','<pattern for api v2>')"/>
</bean>

<security:http request-matcher-ref="apiV1Matcher" ...>
    <!-- config for api v1 requests -->
</security:http>

<security:http request-matcher-ref="apiV2Matcher" ...>
    <!-- config for api v2 requests -->
</security:http>
```

If this resulted in too much duplication, don't use namespace configuration and share beans among filter chains where possible.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know you could do that.